# How to delete when primary key contains two columns, and using safe mode

Tags: mysql

My table is created like this:

```
CREATE TABLE test(
num1 INT,
num2 INT,
PRIMARY KEY(num1, num2)
);
```

what should my delete query look like?

using

```
DELETE FROM test WHERE num1=1 AND num2=2;
```

only result in this error message:

```
Error Code: 1175. You are using safe update mode and you tried to update a table without a WHERE that uses a KEY column To disable safe mode, toggle the option in Preferences -> SQL Editor and reconnect.
```

Also, before you ask, I do know how to turn safe update mode off, but that does not answer my question.

Comment: There is no requirement to delete based on primary key

Comment: Have you tried your query?

Comment: these names does not change. I am not looking into optimization at the moment, I just want to know how to include this primary key into a WHERE, which is required when the safe mode is on.

Comment: @tadman, you are assuming that "player1" and "player2" are names, rather than some unique alphanumeric string that identifies each of those two individuals.  For example, he might be creating a 16 char hash out of the individual's name and ssn and using that as the individual's unique key.

Comment: This is just a practice table, I am not using it for a long term, so please stick to my question, don't worry about anything else.

Comment: @tadman - you called those fields "names" and are saying the id should be independant of the name.  Thus, you **are** assuming those fields are names - probably jumped to the conclusion, as I did at first, that they are first and second name of an individual, rather than unique keys to individuals 1 and 2, associating them as "friends".  For all you know, they are GUID's and defined as varchar to allow for some legacy system that had id's that were shorter.

Comment: @tadman I just removed the noise in my question, I hope that makes my real question stand out a little bit.

Comment: There is no requirement that WHERE uses a key column, or indeed any column at all. Please post the *actual* error message, not what you think it says.

Comment: @EJP there you go.

Comment: @billKarwin Thanks for testing it for me, I just updated my installation, and the error seems to be gone, thank you very much.

Comment: @tadman The rules of 1NF, 2NF, 3NF, etc., are defined in links from your Wiki link. These are the 'normalisation rules', and they do not contain the empirical principle you mentioned.

Comment: @tadman There are many rules, but there are only so many *normalisation* rules, and they are very clearly and elegantly defined, mostly by E.J. Codd in 1970. Read your link and the linked links.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've seen some other Stack Overflow posts where people complain that MySQL Workbench is blocking them from performing safe updates inappropriately.

But I just tried it with your table, both with the PK columns and with a non-key column. When safe mode is enabled, it blocks me from doing updates via non-key column, as it should. But I don't get the error you described.

[image]

I'm using MySQL Workbench 6.3.8 and MySQL Server 8.0.0-dmr.

Perhaps this is a bug in an old version of MySQL or an old version of MySQL Workbench.

Answer (score 0):

Updated mysql and the error is gone.
what a waste of my time.